# How to check when a global object is overwritten in javascript in chrome Dev Tools (or something similar)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm having an issue with a global object being overwritten in javascript.

If you navigate to [this page](https://www.itpro.co.uk/data-insights/analytics/354151/transform-the-operator-experience-with-enhanced-automation-analytics), the dataLayer object is a gtm array, with the modified push method which triggers an event after you call it.

[image]

But if you trigger the Download, the dataLayer object is overwritten and becomes a normal array

[image]

Is there any way in chrome dev tools in which I could add a breakpoint to understand what part of the code is overriding the object?